# CiviRules trigger for a change in participant from one status to another

Tags: civirules

I can not get a rule to trigger on "Event Participant is changed"

Using the condition "Field Value Comparison"

On the field "Participant Status"

If I use "Compare with original value (before the change)?".

It triggers fine if I don't try to check the value before the change but I only want it to trigger if the status changes from (for example) "Registered > Attended".

Any ideas?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Can you add a screen print of the definition of your rule? I'd like to check on my local install :-)

Comment: @ErikH-CiviCooP Thanks. BTW, Civi 5.13.4, CiviRules 2.10-dev (installed from GitLab 2 days ago), WordPress 5.2.3.

Comment: I am not totally clear if the field value comparison is supposed to work that way. If it was my issue I would develop a new condition 'Compare participant status" modeled on the "Compare contribution status".

Comment: This should be working. However there is something strange with the original data. The field is called status_id but in the original data it is called participant_status_id. I think that is caused by the participant get and getsingle api which returns all data prefixed with participant

Comment: So the solution should be to use the participant_status_id in the original value condition and the status_id in the current one.

Comment: Yeah that might be the solution however the field is not available in the drop down. So that is not going to work either. So the answer is it should work but unfortunately it doesn't.

Comment: @ErikH-CiviCooP thanks to you and Jaap for the replies. Should I put in a bug request somewhere? For now the workflow I develop will just have to have a manual "Send an Email" step when a participants status is changed.

Comment: No, if you change your first condition to use participant_status_id it should work. Can you try that?

Comment: @ErikH-CiviCooP Hmmm... There is only one "Participant Status" that can be selected. As Jaap noted above:

"Yeah that might be the solution however the field is not available in the drop down. So that is not going to work either. So the answer is it should work but unfortunately it doesn't."

Am I missing something?

Comment: No you are not, I am :-) You can add a bug on the Gitlab Civrules repo ()? For your information: at CiviCooP we do a CiviRules sprint once a year to fix whatever we can in that sprint. That has just taken place. Would you be in a position to fix thus bug yourself or fund someone to fix it?

Comment: @ErikH-CiviCooP I am not actually a coder but with lots of time and hair pulling I might be able to somehow force this to work. I'm sure it would not be a solution that would be able to be added to the code base. Would funding CiviCooP be an option and if so, do you have an idea on the cost? Thanks

Comment: Yes and I would, but probably best to drop me a mail on erik dot hommel at civicoop dot org?